# 500 internal server error while pushing data to elastic search using rest template

Tags: java, json, spring, elasticsearch, resttemplate

I have a list of json files which have to be pushed to elastic search. I am looping through each file in the list, and creating a RestTemplate object to push the data. Here is my loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=fileCount;i++){
    String fileName="D:/poc/JSON1/file" +date+".csv"+ i + ".json";
    BulkLoadingJsonFiles loadjson=new BulkLoadingJsonFiles();
    loadjson.storeRecords(fileName);
            }
```

And each time this loop is executed I do the following:

```
public void storeRecords(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException
{
    String uri="http://localhost:9200/bd/type/_bulk";
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
    RestTemplate rt=new RestTemplate();
    rt.postForEntity(uri,everything , null);
}
```

This works fine for the first file in the list. Later, for the second file it throws this error:

```
    17:16:04.418 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - POST request for "http://localhost:9200/bd/type/_bulk" resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:384)
    at com.fissionlabs.datageneration.BulkLoadingJsonFiles.storeRecords(BulkLoadingJsonFiles.java:29)
    at com.fissionlabs.practise.Practise.main(Practise.java:96)
```

Comment: Have you tried using spring-data-elasticsearch instead?

Comment: Can you post the output of the elasticsearch server? I.e.: What causes the response?